# Why conda command not found

Tags: conda

I created a conda environment `mogonet` and added the following to `.bashrc` file:
export PATH="path/to/environment/location/bin:$PATH"

```
conda activate mogonet
conda update --all
```

Several packages were added to the environment (e.g., pandas, numpy).

When I try to run my python file as `python3 file.py`, it returned an error:

```
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Comment: One should never manually add a Conda environment’s bin/ to PATH, this is what `conda activate` does dynamically. If you want a specific environment activated at shell start, then auto-activation of **base** should be disabled via `conda config` and a `conda activate mogonet` can be appended to the shell initialization file. Please try some more precise debugging (e.g., only running `import pandas`) and add this to the question body.

Answer (score -1):

EDITED ACCORDING TO UPDATE IN QUESTION:

---

Based on your current question, it seems to me that your Python environment is failing to find `pandas`.  I have a couple of suggestions:

First, enter `which python3` to make sure that its pointing to the correct (magonet) environment.

If it is, enter `conda list` to confirm that `pandas` is installed.

Finally, you can try `python file.py` in the case where `python` points to the correct environment but `python3` does not.

Comment: yes, I ran it as `python3 file.py` when I got the error

Comment: Hmm, that's not what your question showed before, but I have updated my answer accordingly.